# What will happen to azure pipelines after windows 2016 self host agent is removed?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In azure devops i'm getting a warning about the removal of microsoft host agent that uses windows 2016 (vs2017-win2016)
[image]
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4312

What i want to know in regards to that, is if on the pipelines agent jobs where the agent specification is set to windows 2016, if they will automatically start using a newer version of windows agent or stop working completly.
[image]
The github topic seems to indicate that.

The ones were the agent job inherits from the pipeline, i believe there is no problem, besides that for some reason the task(s) are tied to windows 2016.

And what about the pipelines defined in the `Releases` section
[image]

When i click `Create release`

[image]

will it only fail after i try to deploy a created release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your pipelines will fail. There was a situation when MS just "friendly" reminded about depreciation:

[image]

Check this issue: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4312

Releases also contain the same issue. You have to update their jobs to use the new agent type:

[image]

Comment: I will assume that if my agent job inherits an agent specification from the pipeline there is no problem, else i will need to edit it. And in the "Release" section if i create a new release definition will it use a new agent or try to use the one defined on the release pipeline? to me that information is still unclear.

Comment: @Nmaster88 you have to update your releases also (in the job section of each stage). They use the same agents and have the same issues.

Comment: Ok, i guess they will do the same they did for the Hosted and Hosted VS2017 agent pools. If the pipelines are configured to use them, they continue to be configured with them but we are not able to choose them anymore for new pipelines. Because of that i believe that the pipelines will simply fail and will not try to use a newer windows agent.